# find $ \int_0^4\int_0^4\int_0^4 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am looking for an approximation to the nearest integer of
$$ \int_0^4\int_0^4\int_0^4 \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dx\,dy\,dz.$$

Wolfram alpha gives up and says "*computation time exceeded*".

I tried, unsuccessfully, to approximate the measure of the sets
$$ E_N = \{(x,y,z):x,y,z\in[0,4],\; x^2+y^2+z^2\in[N,N+1]\},$$
but in some cases the volume of the intersection between a cube and a spherical shell is very hard to compute.

Comment: not sure how to start, can we use spherical coordinates, but i am having trouble with the bounds there

Comment: Try to draw the domain of integration: you allow each $x,y,z$ to vary from $0$ to $4$, so you're integrating over a cube with one vertex at the origin and side lengths equal to 4.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%2B+z%5E2%29%5E%281%2F2%29+dx+dy+dz%2C+x%3D0..4%2C+y%3D0..4%2C+z%3D0..4

Comment: @Hurkyl: Thanks, that's useful. I have looked briefly at WA but never stumbled across the relevant syntax.

Comment: Mhm, where have I seen this question/user before...

Comment: @Shahar: Are you going to tell us, or are we supposed to wait for the first episode of the next season, if there is even going to be such season?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Wait for the next season.

Comment: @Shahar: Winter is coming.

Comment: Hi guys, is the symbol for centroid and centre of mass same !

Comment: @loading.... Depends what symbols you use...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Numerical integration gives that the closest integer is $246$, since
$$I=\int_{[0,4]^3}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,d\mu=245.91154\ldots$$
The best way to achieve a good accuracy "by hand" is to study the pdf of $\sqrt{X^2+Y^2+Z^2}$ when $X,Y,Z$ are three independent random variable with a uniform distribution over $[0,4]$, by eventually using some quantitative form of the Central Limit Theorem.

Since $\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\frac{16}{3}$, the Jensen's inequality gives $I\leq 4^4=256$.

Anyway, such integral also admits the closed form:
$$ I = \frac{32}{3} \left(6 \sqrt{3}-\pi +\log\left(3650401+2107560 \sqrt{3}\right)\right).$$

Answer (score 9):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With
$\ds{\pars{~\mbox{spherical coordinates}~}\ r = \root{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}}$, we have
$\ds{\nabla\cdot\pars{r\,\vec{r}} = {\vec{r} \over r}\cdot\vec{r} + 3r = 4r}$:

---

\begin{align}&\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{4}%
\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
=\int_{\bracks{0,4}^{3}}r\,\dd^{3}\vec{r}
=\int_{\bracks{0,4}^{3}}{1 \over 4}\,\nabla\cdot\pars{r\,\vec{r}}\,\dd^{3}\vec{r}
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 4}\int_{\rm S}r\,\vec{r}\cdot\dd\vec{\rm S}
={1 \over 4}\int_{\braces{0,4}^{2}}\root{16 + y^{2} + z^{2}}\,4\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[3mm]&+{1 \over 4}\int_{\braces{0,4}^{2}}\root{x^{2} + 16 + z^{2}}\,4
\,\dd x\,\dd z
+{1 \over 4}\int_{\braces{0,4}^{2}}\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + 16}\,4\,\dd x\,\dd y
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}&\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{4}%
\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
=3\int_{\braces{0,4}^{2}}\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + 16}\,\dd x\,\dd y
\\[3mm]&=3\int_{0}^{4}\int_{0}^{4}\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + 16}\,\dd y\,\dd x
=192\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + 1}\,\dd y\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=48\int_{0}^{1}\left\{2\left[\root{x^{2} + 2} + \left(x^{2} + 1\right)
\ln\left(\root{x^{2} + 2} + 1\right)\right] - \left(x^{2} + 1\right)
\ln\left(x^{2} + 1\right)\right\}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\bbox[15px,border:1px solid navy]{\ds{
64\left[\root{3} + \ln\left(7 + 4\root{3}\right)\right] - {32\pi \over3}}}
\approx {\tt 245.9115409}
\end{align}

```
// monteCarlo0.cc
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
typedef long double ldouble;
typedef unsigned long long ullong;
const ldouble RANDMAX1=ldouble(RAND_MAX) + 1.0L;
const ullong ITER=100000000ULL; // One hundred million
ldouble X,Y;

inline ldouble f(ldouble x,ldouble y)
{
 return sqrt(x*x + y*y + 1.0L);
}

inline ldouble f()
{
 X=rand()/RANDMAX1;
 Y=rand()/RANDMAX1;
 return (f(X,Y) + f(X,1.0L - Y) + f(1.0L - X,Y) + f(1.0L - X,1.0L - Y))/4.0L;
}

int main()
{
 ldouble suma=0;

 for ( ullong n=0 ; n<ITER ; ++n ) suma+=f();
 cout<<setprecision(50)<<(192.0L*(suma/ITER))<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

It runs for 7 sec.

Result: $\ds{\color{#f00}{ 245.911}07650843407733676215798368502873927354812622}$.

Comment: I'm kinda blinded by all those braces and declarations and order symbols :-).

Answer (score 5):

And now for something entirely random:

Monte Carlo integration gives

```
Monte Carlo (n=1000) estimate=245.876995211
Monte Carlo (n=10000) estimate=246.605709455
Monte Carlo (n=100000) estimate=245.440557832
Monte Carlo (n=1000000) estimate=245.841098533
Monte Carlo (n=10000000) estimate=245.946260986
```

Generated from the following:

```
import math
import random

def norm(x):
    return math.sqrt(sum([xi*xi for xi in x]))

# returns a uniformly distributed sample in [0, 4]^3
def unif():
    return [random.uniform(0, 4) for i in (1, 2, 3)]

area = 4*4*4
for total_count in (1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000):
    sum_func = 0
    for i in xrange(total_count):
        x_samp = unif()
        sum_func += norm(x_samp)

    est_volume = sum_func/float(total_count)*area

    print("Monte Carlo (n=%s) estimate=%s" % (total_count, est_volume))
```

Comment: How quick did this run for you? Monte Carlo integration is wonderful.

Comment: About 26s clock time on my i7 4 core laptop.

Comment: Not bad at all.

Comment: what software did u use for calculation

Comment: The language is Python (2.7). Just run the script above.